# Overlay contour onto new image

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I am extracting an object from an image and overlaying this onto a background to generate scenes for a computer vision task. Random positioning, sizing, rotation, and filtering will be added each time a scene is generated.

The problem I am facing is that, unless the object is a perfect vertical rectangle, I get a black border when overlaying the image.

How do I make the area outside the contour transparent when overlaying?

Find below some example code and output.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import io

#Import Card
card = io.imread('https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/BZoAAOSwj0RfkZuD/s-l225.jpg') 
plt.imshow(card)

#Import Background
background = io.imread('https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/dtd/images/cracked/cracked_0049.jpg') 
plt.imshow(background)
```

[image: card]
[image: background]

```
#Find contours and extract card
edged=cv2.Canny(card,30,200)
contours, hierarchy=cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contour = [c for c in contours if c.size >=1300][0]

#Crop out background
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
card_cropped = card[y:y+h, x:x+w]

#Resize
card_cropped_resized = cv2.resize(card_cropped, (int(card_cropped.shape[1]/0.8), int(card_cropped.shape[0]/0.8)))

#Generate Scene
card_cropped_resized_grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(card_cropped_resized, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
background_grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

h, w = card_cropped_resized_grayscale.shape[:2]
hh, ww = background_grayscale.shape[:2]

yoff = round(hh/4)
xoff = round(ww/4)

xMin = xoff
yMin = yoff
xMax = xoff+w
yMax = yoff+h

scene = background_grayscale.copy()
scene[yMin:yMax, xMin:xMax] = card_cropped_resized_grayscale

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(scene,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB))
```

[image: generated scene]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your concern, here is a more robust solution using masked compositing in Python/OpenCV. We create a filled mask from the contour of the card and crop the card and mask to the bounding box of the contour. Next we insert the card into the background at the desired location. And we insert the mask into a black background image of the same size as the background. Then we composite the original background and the new background with the card inserted using the mask to control which is used.

Background:

[image]

Card:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import io    

#Import Card
card = io.imread('https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/BZoAAOSwj0RfkZuD/s-l225.jpg') 

# Apply median filter to card
card_median = cv2.medianBlur(card, 3)

#Import Background
background = io.imread('https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/dtd/images/cracked/cracked_0049.jpg') 
hh, ww = background.shape[:2]

#Find edges of card
edged=cv2.Canny(card_median,30,200)
plt.imshow(edged)
plt.show()

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
cntr = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw white filled contour on black background the size of card 
card_mask = np.zeros_like(card)
cv2.drawContours(card_mask, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

# erode contour just a little to ensure contour encloses no black from outside card
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (3,3))
card_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(card_mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

#Get bounding box
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)

# crop card and card_mask
card_cropped = card[y:y+h, x:x+w]
card_mask_cropped = card_mask[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# define insert location and size
yoff = round(hh/4)
xoff = round(ww/4)

xMin = xoff
yMin = yoff
xMax = xoff+w
yMax = yoff+h

# insert cropped card into background
scene = background.copy()
scene[yMin:yMax, xMin:xMax] = card_cropped

# insert card_mask into black background the size of background image (and make single channel)
mask = np.zeros_like(background)
mask[yMin:yMax, xMin:xMax] = card_mask_cropped
mask = mask[:,:,0]

#composite scene with background using mask
scene_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(scene, scene, mask=mask)
background_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(background, background, mask=(255-mask))
result = cv2.add(scene_masked,background_masked)

# show results
plt.imshow(scene)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()

# save results
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("card_composite.jpg",result)
```

Result:

[image]

Here is the results from using this card image:

Card:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was getting errors in your contour when trying your code. So I made some changes, most notably, to use thresholding rather than Canny edges for the basis of the contours. To remove the black border, I just eroded the thresholded image before getting its contour.  You could do the same by simply editing your x,y,w,h to remove a few pixels all around. The reason you get the black border is that your Canny edge image has noise, which makes the contour larger. But mostly because the shape of the card is not rectangular, but narrower at the top than bottom. So the rectangular bounding box will be the dimensions of the largest of the top or bottom and the black is what is between the actual area and the bounding box. Adding a median filter after the Canny edge operation would improve that part, but not the shape issue.

Input:

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import io

#Import Card
card = io.imread('https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/BZoAAOSwj0RfkZuD/s-l225.jpg') 
plt.imshow(card)
#plt.show()

#Import Background
background = io.imread('https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/dtd/images/cracked/cracked_0049.jpg') 
plt.imshow(background)
#plt.show()

#Find contours and extract card
#edged=cv2.Canny(card,30,200)
edged = cv2.cvtColor(card, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.threshold(edged, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (5,5))
edged = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
plt.imshow(edged)
#plt.show()


#contours, hierarchy=cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
#contour = [c for c in contours if c.size >=1300][0]
contours = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)


#Crop out background
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
card_cropped = card[y:y+h, x:x+w]

#Resize
card_cropped_resized = cv2.resize(card_cropped, (int(card_cropped.shape[1]/0.8), int(card_cropped.shape[0]/0.8)))

#Generate Scene
card_cropped_resized_grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(card_cropped_resized, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
background_grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

h, w = card_cropped_resized_grayscale.shape[:2]
hh, ww = background_grayscale.shape[:2]

yoff = round(hh/4)
xoff = round(ww/4)

xMin = xoff
yMin = yoff
xMax = xoff+w
yMax = yoff+h

scene = background_grayscale.copy()
scene[yMin:yMax, xMin:xMax] = card_cropped_resized_grayscale

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(scene,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB))
plt.show()

cv2.imwrite("scene_grayscale.jpg",scene)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The code works fine for the example card. 

However, I tested on a card with a more aggressive slant and it produces a border. [example](https://imgur.com/a/2672Ixj).

Sorry if I didn't make it clear in my question, but I'm looking for a solution that works regardless of how the rectangular card is orientated.